# Error in sum(parent) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r

I used this for-loop

```r
for(i in 1:length(ids)) {
   print(paste0(i," of ",length(ids)))
   parent = ids[i]
    if(parent > 1) {
      while(sum(parent) > 1) {
        childs_location = grep(paste0("^",parent, "$"), nodes[, 1])
        parents_id = nodes[childs_location,2]
        path[[i]] = c(path[[i]], parents_id)
        parent = parents_id
      }
  }
}
```

and get this error

> Error in sum(parent): invalid 'type' (character) of argument

The class of `ids` is character. Is this causing this error?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Do you mind making your example reproducible by providing necessary (toy) data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example As your code exhibits several issues please provide expected output or a detailed description of what you are trying to achieve as well.

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting `sum(ids)` to mean if it is a character. Do you want `sum(as.numeric(ids))`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.